# C# UWP Change Image-Source in ListView-Binding

Tags: c#, image, listview, uwp

I have a C# UWP solution for myself and I have defined the special manifest `broadFileSystemAccess`, so I can access all files from my PC directly.

I fill a `ListView` by setting the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` to a `ObservableCollection<someModel>` variable (more details below). After tapping on it, I want to change it.

In class `someModel` I set the path to the image and the content as `BitmapImage`. I do this because, the file is on some path on my PC, e.g. `E:\pix\some path\image.jpg`, then read this file into the `BitmapImage`, so I can later bind it as the Image source. This is super slow and inefficient, but it works for now and I'll change it in the future.

```
class someModel
{
   public string ImagePath { get; set; }
   public BitmapImage ImageContent { get; set; }
}
```

and my XAML image:

```
<Image DataContext="{x:Bind Mode=TwoWay}" Source="{x:Bind ImageContent, Mode=OneWay}" Width="400" Stretch="UniformToFill" Tapped="lvImageEditImage_Tapped" />
```

my function `lvImageEditImage_Tapped` :

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker
{
    ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
    SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
};

StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    var item = (sender as Image).DataContext as someModel;
    item.ImagePath = file.Path;

    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
    }
    item.ImageContent = bitmapImage;
}
```

While I now get the path, the image content `bitmapImage` doesn't change the viewed image.

Why doesn't the image update to the new `BitmapImage` content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to the data model.

```cs
public class someModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BitmapImage _imageContent;
    public BitmapImage ImageContent
    {
        get => _imageContent;
        set
        {
            _imageContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

After inheriting the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, you can use `{x:Bind ImageContent, Mode=OneWay}` to complete the binding. When the data source is modified, the UI interface will be notified to change.

Best regards.